# justify text in label xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Am trying to **justify text** in **Label Xamarin Forms** but couldnt , 
 how  to justify the text (not styling justify only) same like a picture  without using webview
[image]

I have attached my code but its justify left only

```
        string strText="MY LONG TEXT IS GOING HERE";

        var lblMSG = new Label {TextColor = Color.Black };

        lblMSG.Text=strText;
        lblMSG.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        lblMSG.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
        lblMSG.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
        lblMSG.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        StackLayout  stk=   new StackLayout { Children = { lblMSG}, BackgroundColor = Color.White ,HorizontalOptions =LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }
```

Comment: Do you mean styling the text? If yes, you need to make it manually.

Comment: not styling only justifying - for styling I use FormattedString()

Comment: "lblMSG.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;" makes the text start from the left. Try changing it to TextAlignment.Center.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a label. I used a HtmlWebViewSource.

An example is below:

XAML:

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="webViewLayout"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <!-- view codebehind for WebView for overview text -->
 </StackLayout>
```

Code Behind of XAML (viewModel.Model.Content = strText in your case):

```
var browser = new WebView();
browser.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
browser.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

var source = new HtmlWebViewSource();
var text = "<html>" +
        "<body  style=\"text-align: justify;\">" +
        String.Format("<p>{0}</p>", viewModel.Model.Content) +
        "</body>" +
        "</html>";
source.Html = text ;
browser.Source = source;
webViewLayout.Children.Add(browser);
```

Comment: Simple, but effective. Thank you very much.

Comment: In your given solution can i change the font ? i need "montserrat" font to my <body> element without connecting to Internet please give me any solution or any idea?

Comment: You need to add font file to your project and then it can be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about stretching the multi-line text to full width (text must touch left and right sides of the block), you can use platform renderer. [See this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062368/xamarin-forms-label-justify/53945760#53945760).