# How to justify the text of label in .NET MAUI?

Tags: label, maui, text-justify

I have a label that displays on more than a line and I would like to justify the text in it (align left and right).

I've been trying to achieve this through the handler, but I have no clue how to do it.
What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: You should be using `HorizontalTextAlignment/VerticalTextAlignment` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: Are you able to swap out the Label for a WebView?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39044377/881441 ?