# xamarin.forms to justify the Binding Text

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to justify the Binding Text ?

My code is shown below but it didn't help me

```xml
<StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="20,20,20,20" Spacing="2">
    <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" XAlign="Start" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" 
           x:Name="aboutUs" TextColor="Black"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: [See this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062368/xamarin-forms-label-justify/53945760#53945760), easily done with platform renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `Xamarin.Forms` doesn't gives you a way to do it directly.

Longer answer:
The only valid values for `HorizontalTextAlignment` (which you should use instead of the deprecated `XAlign`) are `Start`, `Center` and `End` and doesn't provide any way to justify the text. So you can't justify a label.

If you really want to have justified text, you could:

- implement your own LabelRenderer that supports it;
- or, simpler, as it's an `About Us` box, use a `WebView` and rely on the HTML engine to justify the text for you.