# Label text not justified managed by XAML code

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am new in Xamarin mobile app and using the grid in my application. But label text not justified control by XAML. searching related this, code available only c#.kindly help me, anyone, to control by XAML. Attached my code below image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqSxG.png

Comment: What do you want the app to look like, you can show a picture to illustrate the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with visual studio Mac xaml editor. Try using visual studio windows for best experience with xaml. VS windows even has xaml formatter extension.

If you are on a Mac, use Parallel to run VS windows

Comment: The question is about how to justify the rendered text in an application when using the Xamarin.Forms Label control, not about how the code's text appears in the IDE.

Answer (score -1):

If centering the text via HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" is not what you're after, then unfortunately, you have to use a custom renderer to truly fully justify the text. Refer to the [answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062368/xamarin-forms-label-justify) with the code.

Comment: A custom renderer is a c# code. is possible in xaml code for justified text?

Comment: Once you add that C# code (the custom renderer code in the platform-specific projects, and then the ExtendedLabel control class in the main .NET Standard project of your Xamarin.Forms solution), then just add that new control into your XAML, so instead of <Label Text="blah"/> you'd put in *<ExtendedLabel Text="blah" JustifyText=True/>*   -  if this is the first time you're going through this, I would recommend reading this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/