# How do I center multiline text in a label

Tags: xamarin.forms

Has anyone figured out how to center (or justify or in any way horizontally effect) text in a Xamarin Forms Label with `LineBreakMode=WordWrap`? Without using a WebView (or similar)?

All `HorizontalOptions` entries are cheerfully ignored in this code snippet:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label
        Margin="75,0,75,0"
        FontAttributes="Italic"
        FontSize="Large"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
        Text="Live life as though nobody is watching, and express yourself as though everyone Is listening."
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTGRF.jpg).

Comment: Reference this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062368/xamarin-forms-label-justify)

Comment: try using `HorizontalTextAlignment`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" in this case.

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label
        Margin="75,0,75,0"
        FontAttributes="Italic"
        FontSize="Large"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
        Text="Live life as though nobody is watching, and express yourself as though everyone Is listening."
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Neat. I guess that makes sense, as `HorizontalOptions` only pertains to the location of the `Label` within the parent, right? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your code

> HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label
        Margin="75,0,75,0"
        FontAttributes="Italic"
        FontSize="Large"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
        Text="Live life as though nobody is watching, and express yourself as though everyone Is listening."
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```